# How to maintain locality of HBase when it runs in a container like docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, hbase

I'm trying to deploy an HBase cluster using k8s. I have some bare metal machines in which k8s and hdfs is running. I understand if I deploy the HBase on these machines directly, the locality is just fine. But what if these services are running in a container? Just like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnSdb.png)

Personally I think the locality will be zero though the RegionServer runs in the same node, cause the RegionServer will register a different hostname to the HMaster with the datanode which registers to the NameNode.

What I should do if I want to maintain the locality of this HBase cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Even if HBase puts in different nodes during loading data , we will still be able to achieve data locality.

Whenever a huge amount of data is ingested during non peak hours major compaction can be run so that the deteriorating data locality will be regained by moving data to the desired region server.

> Personally I think the locality will be zero though the RegionServer
> runs in the same node, cause the RegionServer will register a
> different hostname to the HMaster with the datanode which registers to
> the NameNode.

Even with that it won't be the case. HBase will handle that.